# Seeds relations at the sametime in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two models in laravel with a OneToOne relation, Team and Venue.
I'm trying to populate both tables, but each one needs the id as a foreign key of the other table from another model. For example, if I want to create a Venue, I need the Team id, but it doesn't exist yet. And vice versa.

`Array with the data`

```php
array:2 [▼
  "team" => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Belgium"
    "country" => "Belgium"
    "founded" => 1895
    "national" => true
  ]
  "venue" => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 173
    "name" => "Stade Roi Baudouin"
    "address" => "Avenue de Marathon 135/2"
    "city" => "Brussel"
    "capacity" => 50093
    "surface" => "grass"
  ]
]
```

`Migration CreateTeamsTable`

```php
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("id")->primary();
    $table->string("name");
    $table->string("country");
    $table->integer("founded");
    $table->boolean("national");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`Migration CreateVenuesTable`

```php
Schema::create('venues', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("id")->primary();
    $table->string("name");
    $table->string("address");
    $table->string("city");
    $table->integer("capacity");
    $table->string("surface");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`Migration CreateTeamVenueForeign`

```php
Schema::table('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('venue_id')->constrained()->onDelete("Cascade");
});
```

`Migration CreateVenueTeamForeign`

```php
Schema::table('venues', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('team_id')->constrained();
});
```

`Team Model`

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = array('id', 'name', 'country', 'founded', 'national', 'venue_id');

    public function venue()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Venue');
    }
}
```

`Venue Model`

```php
class Venue extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = array('id', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'capacity', 'surface', 'team_id');

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Team');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you you need a circular relation - `venu_id` on teams and `team_id` on venues table?

Comment: It´s not correct? For example, If a search a Team, I need to know his venue and If I search a Venue, I need to know belogs to a what team.

Comment: You can implement a hasOne relation at one end and a belongsTo at the other end. For ex you can implement Venue hasOne Team and Team belongsTo Venue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OneToOne relation requires one foreign key, not two. If you create foreign keys in both tables, you won't be able to add any record without constraint violation.

Take a look at [this paragraph](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship) in Laravel documentation.
If one of your entities has `hasOne()` relation, the other one should have `belongsTo()`. Which one will have which depends on which table you put the foreign key in.

Comment: Correct, I wanted to be smarter than the documentation. My fault. Even so, I'm turning it around and I'm messed up because I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I updated the code. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I missed `public $incrementing = false;` in the `Team` Model because my data has an own id... I revert my question to the original and accept your answer because it´s the correct answer. Thank you so much.